# How to make discord.js 11 not case sensitive?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an anti swear made in discord js 11 and it uses a file called bannedwords.txt. Is there a way I can make it read the file without being case sensitive. For instance if one of the banned words was chicken, I wanna make it so it bans CHICKen, CHicken, Chicken, chicken, ChiCKeN, you get the point. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toLowerCase()` method of strings to achieve this. Simply call it on both the message being checked for swearing, and/or on the banned word it is being checked for. Here's an example:

```
checkProfanity: function(message, bannedWords) {
    var words = message.split(' ');
    for (var word of words) {
      if (bannedWords.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the modification necessary in your [punishment.js](https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot/blob/1a5eb172ed26d589fee0be8e468afa54c91dc7ff/censor/punishment.js#L31) file to make your filter case insensitive. Since all of the banned words in your `bannedwords.txt` file are lowercase, we can simply convert each individual word of the message to lowercase to make the comparison between the word and banned word possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response heres my git hub link for the bot :https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot

Comment: Ok thanks, I will update my answer with your code.