# Banned Words space sensitivity?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot: https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot. It has a censor that works great except for one shortcoming. In the banned words.txt there are my banned words. I don't want to curse so let's say one of the words is Chicken. If I were to Spam Chicken without spacing it, the anti swear won't remove it. Is there a way I can get it to remove the message even if a swear word was used?

Discord JS V 11 btw

Comment: have you tried using `Regex` ?

Comment: no, I have not. Never heard of it, but after googling it, sounds pretty good. How do I implement it?

Comment: i dont know much about regex but you can find out something more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) like `"chicken".match(/chicken/g)` would output an array `['chicken']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sfue in the comments, you can use Regex to achieve this. In fact, regex could be used to solve both this issue and [the issue I helped you with earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259080/how-to-make-discord-js-11-not-case-sensitive/65259160#65259160) at once. Here's how it would go:

```
checkProfanity: function(message, bannedWords) {
    var words = message.split(' ');
    for (var word of words) {
       if (bannedWords.some(element => word.match(new RegExp(element, "i")) && element != "")) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This uses a combination of a few things that weren't in your code before. First off is [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which is used to check if at least one element in an array passes the test specified by the supplied function. This is very useful in your situation, since you have an array of banned words and you want to check to see if any one of those banned words is present in your message. Second is [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), which is used for matching text with a pattern. We are using one `RegExp` flag here: `i` (meaning case insensitive). This flag is crucial to solving your earlier issue. Lastly, we pull together our use of all of the components mentioned above with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which is used to retrieve the result of attempting to match a String to a Regex pattern. `Match()` paired with our Regex will return a value if any banned word appears in one of the message's words, and in a case insensitive manner due to our `i` flag, solving both issues at once.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Although it did work I'm introduced to the new problem of it deleting any word it sees.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Every message sent is being deleted.

Comment: Every single message? If you can provide an example of a message that gets deleted by the bot, I can look into it.

Comment: I could no joke any scam type any word in the English language and it deletes it. I have no clue as to why. Here is my punishment.js

https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot/blob/master/censor/punishment.js

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can find out why it does that. Luckily `String.match()` returns an output, so it should be fairly simple to see what specific banned word the code thinks it's found in the message.

Comment: Where should I be looking for it? Right now it is DMing me this message:

Your message has been deleted for profanity and logged.

Comment: Well, if you replace the `return true` in checkProfanity with `return bannedWords.find(element => word.match(new RegExp(element, "i")))`, then the checkProfanity method will return the specific banned word it detected in your message (if a banned word was detected). Doing that replacement shouldn't affect your code at all, but you could add the output of checkProfanity to the DM message and it will send you the exact banned word that it detected in your message.

Comment: And I honestly don't know what the issue is that's causing the problem. I added your bannedwords.txt, `Initialize.loadBannedWords()`, and your `checkProfanity()` method to a test project, and when I sent the message "test this thing" it did not detect any banned words at all (and returned false) which is the expected result.

Comment: You used the files in my GitHub and it worked fine? What OS?

Comment: Windows. I didn't create a full discord bot, I simply used the 3 files mentioned and checked it against hard-coded strings.

Comment: You might also want to check your bannedWords array. If any of the elements of that array are an empty string (`""`) then `checkProfanity()` will always return true. You can protect against that by adding an `&& element != ""` in  `checkProfanity`. I will update my answer to include that.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I just redownloaded my GitHub project and it works fine now. I prolly screwed something up earlier.